# how to repeat or loop an applescript

Tags: email, loops, applescript, repeat

I was looking for an option to color all unread mails in apple mail and I found the following script

```
tell application "Mail"

set background color of (messages of inbox whose read status is false) to red --unread
set background color of (messages of inbox whose read status is true) to none --default read

end tell
```

I added this script to a mail rule, which applies to every message, then it works almost perfect. The only problem is that it works only for one time. So if I get a new message, than the script doesn't notice it (so it is not red, only bold), or if I read an email, then it will be still red.
Please can someone help me, that the script will run in loop, or that the script will run each second.

Just for information, I´m an windows user (mac is really new for me) and I was looking for an scheduled task option, but I didn't found such easy thing on my mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options to run scheduled tasks. Apple suggests to use the "launchd" agent. Just google "launchd tutorial" for many examples.

The basics are this... you create a plist file (an xml text file with the .plist file extension) with whatever instructions you want and put that it in the folder ~/Library/LaunchAgents. The tutorials will show you how to create many different kinds of plist files. Once you add your plist to that folder then logout/login to make it take effect. To disable a plist fie from running then remove it from the folder and logout/login. It's that simple.

As an example plist for your specific request, this one will run your applescript every 60 seconds...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myName.myProgramName</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>/path/to/applescript.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So in that plist example you just need to put your values in "com.myName.myProgramName", "/path/to/applescript.scpt", and "60" which is the number of seconds to run the applescript.

NOTE: you should name your plist file the same name as you give for "com.myName.myProgramName" with ".plist" as its file extension.

Good luck.

Comment: hi regulus6633, thanks for your answer, but I´m not able to get it work.
I created the the plist file with the "TextEdit" application, i hope this is also ok?!
I uploaded my script, my plist file and a screenshot to Dropbox - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6isbd0zap9r3iiu/3files.zip?dl=0 maybe you´ll find some problem.
On the screenshot you can see, where my script file and where my plist file is located

Comment: I looked at your files. The plist file is strange. I get strange characters at the top like it's a rich text file saved from TextEdit. You must save it as a plain text file instead of RTF. So look under the Format menu and choose "make plain text" before you save it. Also the label string in the file shouldn't have ".plist". Also the path to your applescript uses "~". I'm not sure if that works. I would change that to "/users/username". Try it again with those changes.

Comment: thanks great it works now.
and yes i have created the plist file with the "TextEdit" app, but i already mentioned this i my first comment. Thanks for the tip with the "make plain text" I´m a completely new apple user, i didn't knew that things.

Comment: i have still one question, till the implementation from yesterday the apple mail app will start automatically, if i boot my Macbook.
Is it anyhow possible, that apple mail will not start automatically?

Comment: No. The Mail app is started by your applescript because the Mail app must be open for it to work. Maybe the "launch" command will help because that tries to open the program in the background rather than it coming onto your screen. So put "launch" above your first "set background color" line of code. You can also quit Mail when the code is finished by putting "quit" after the second line.

Comment: your solution hasn't worked, because the app either still started in forefront or it started and closed immediately and this is very awful if you want to work with mail, but with your tip i found the correct solution in google --> https://culturedcode.com/forums/read.php?7,58279

Comment: and my code is looking now like this:  
tell application "Mail"
 set background color of (messages of inbox whose read status is false) to red --unread
 set background color of (messages of inbox whose read status is true) to none --default read
 set visible of "Mail" to false
end tell

Comment: i´ve bad news: the code (which i thought on 02.april) is not working, and i didn't found any other solution.
I will live with it, that the "Mail" app will start automatically at each boot of the system.