# OSX application permissions only allow them to be opened by one user account

Tags: macos, applescript

I have written a very basic AppleScript application which should connect our users to the network shares whenever they execute it. I want to be able to put this in everybody's Applications folder so it is accessible to whichever user logs in.

```
tell application Finder
    mount volume \\server\share
    mount volume \\server\share
    mount volume \\server\share
end tell
```

The user account that moves the app from its location on the server to the Applications folder is able to execute this fine, however no other users are able to do this. Instead they get an error saying:

```
You do not have permission to open the application "Network Volumes Connection".
```

What permissions do I need to assign to the app to allow every user that logs on the ability to execute it?

EDIT

After granting read & write access to everyone the error changes to

```
"The application "Network Volumes Connections" can't be opened."
```

and nobody - not even the person that copied the application over - is able to execute it now.

There are also several messages displayed in the console relating to this.

```
Finder: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=111 label=com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.Network-Volumes-Connections.95172 path=/Applications/Network Volumes Connections.app/Contents/MacOS/applet flags=1 : LaunchApplicationClient.cp #1136 LaunchApplicationViaLaunchDJobLabel() q=com.apple.root.default.qos
```

.

```
Finder: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=111 label=com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.Network-Volumes-Connections.95172 path=/Applications/Network Volumes Connections.app/Contents/MacOS/applet flags=1
```

.

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd: (com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.Network-Volumes-Connections.95172[951]) Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 13: Permission denied: /Applications/Network Volumes Connections.app/Contents/MacOS/applet
```

.

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd: (com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.Network-Volumes-Connections.95172[951]) Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
```

.

```
WindowServer: _CGXSetWinowHasKeyAppearance: Operation on a window 0x12 requiring rights kCGSWindowRightOwner by caller Dashboard
```

.

```
WindowServer: _CGXSetWinowHasMainAppearance: Operation on a window 0x12 requiring rights kCGSWindowRightOwner by caller Dashboard
```

.

```
mdworker: code validation failed in the process of getting signing information: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -67062.)"
```

Comment: Finder's info window (select the app, CMD-I) shows permissions and you can also change them.

Comment: This shouldn't be a application at all; you can mount network drives through *Login Items* or configuring the auto-mounter.

Comment: Login items didn't suit our needs, so instead a plist inside /library/launchagents calls a scpt file which mounts the volumes for any user that logs in to the Mac. Login items only work for that particular user. I can see what the permissions are  and I'm aware to change them, but whenever I change them it doesn't work. For example Adobe Bridge has System:Read & Write, Admin:Read & Write, and Everyone:Read only access, but when I assign this to my app no one is able to open the app and I get the error "The application "Network Volumes Connection" can't be opened."

Comment: Ah, the error message changed! I think AppleScript Apps write stuff back into their bundle (default stuff and may be properties?) so maybe it won't work without write permissions -

Comment: Tried adding read & write access to everyone, but still getting the second error message. The console errors say a bit that I'll add to the question...

Comment: This is is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345592/how-to-repeat-or-loop-an-applescript - since it uses launchd to execute a compiled script via osascript and does not start an application - maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Mhm that's what I've used to get the script working on login, and that's working ok. The only issue now is I want an app too, so that if a user disconnects from a share for whatever reason they can just double-click the app to execute it and reconnect to the shares they've lost. I'm aware they can Go > Connect to Server, but this would be much more convenient for them.

Comment: The launchd plist for me is working perfectly, so that is not an issue. When every user logs in, a separate scpt file runs and maps every network drive, so the plist is not the issue. Separately from this my app does not run when invoked manually. This is what I'm trying to get fixed.